# Figuring out a regex for possible times

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to construct a regular expression for time:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^\d{1,2}:?\d{0,2}?:?\d{1,2}?$', '01:10:')
[]
>>> re.findall(r'^\d{1,2}:?\d{0,2}?:?\d{1,2}?$', '01:10')
['01:10']
```

Why does the first one not work but the second one does? Is there an issue with the `:?` or something for the optional `semicolon` ?

Comment: @user202729 out of curiosity, why?

Comment: If you have `^` and `$`, should you just use `fullmatch` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no match for string `01:10:` because your regex `\d{1,2}?` will match 1 or 2 digits as few times as possible which is called **lazy matching**.

Please understand that:

```
\d{1,2}?
```

is not same as:

```
(?:\d{1,2})?
```

If you have your regex as:

```
^\d{1,2}:?\d{0,2}:?(?:\d{1,2})?$
```

[Then it will match both inputs](https://regex101.com/r/pGaASg/2)

It can further be refactored to:

```
^\d{1,2}:?\d{0,2}:?\d{0,2}$
```

to allow for an empty match in the end.

Also note that there is no use of `\d{0,2}?` which is same as `\d{0,2}`.